# Can I use a standard event listener on a react plugin from my WordPress theme JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, wordpress

There is a React plugin that generates a WordPress form and I want to add a focusout type of event to the inputs from my theme JS. I tried the following from my theme JS

```
$(document).on('focusout','.formInput input',function(){
        console.log('test');
});

// also tried this
$(".formInput").focusout(function() {
        console.log('test');
});

// and this
$(".formInput").on("blur", function(){
        console.log('test');
});

//and this
document.getElementById( "firstName" ).onblur = function(){
        console.log('test');
};
```

and none of these work. No errors. It seems as though the firing order is wrong. Is it how React is building the DOM? Any ideas from anyone on what I should be doing?

-thx

Comment: It seems like you go from `.formInput input` to `.formInput`. So which one is it, does your input have the class of `.formInput` or is it wrapped by an element with that class?  The first one should work if you just use the correct selector.

Comment: .formInput is the class assigned to the inputs. They render as <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control formInput" placeholder="First name">

Comment: So for your first option, try `.formInput` as the selector.

Comment: Just tried only using: $(document).on('focusout', '.formInput', function(){ console.log('test'); }); no console log at all. Is this a react dom thing in the plugin which is preventing the event form firing?

Comment: what plugin are you using that adds the React based form?

Comment: It's an in-house plugin. I initially wanted this code to run independently of the plugin. I finally gave up on that idea and added the event directly in React.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was not working was because React uses a virtual DOM not an actual DOM. The key was to use the body selector and then a jQuery 'on' function:

```
$("body").on('focusout', '.formInput', function(){
   console.log('test');
});
```